# Snowflake Overwrites Column Names using COPY INTO

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have one query only that fails to copy column headers in the results when executed as `COPY INTO`. I have `HEADER=TRUE` and I'm assigning explicit names using `AS`. The behavior occurs when I am not explicitly assigning names as well.

If the query is run without `COPY INTO` the results are generated correctly.

Query

```
COPY INTO 's3://<my_bucket>'
FROM (
SELECT 
  col1 AS "alpha",
  col2 AS "beta",
  col3 AS "charlie", 
  col4 AS "delta"
FROM
  "table_1"
INNER JOIN 
    "table_2"
ON
    col1 = col3
AND
    col2 = 'foo'
AND
    col4 > 1234
     )
FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE='PARQUET' FIELD_DELIMITER=',' record_delimiter = '\n' field_optionally_enclosed_by='"')
HEADER=TRUE 
SINGLE=FALSE 
OVERWRITE=TRUE 
MAX_FILE_SIZE = 5368709120
credentials=(AWS_KEY_ID='<my_id>'
AWS_SECRET_KEY='<my_key>');
```

Results

```
ROW   C0    C1    C2    C3
 1    foo   bar   baz   beetle
```

Desired Results

```
ROW   alpha    beta    charlie    delta
 1    foo      bar     baz        beetle
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, COPY INTO with headers included should work.  Here's an example for parquet:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-unload-considerations.html#unloading-a-relational-table-to-parquet-with-multiple-columns

Just for testing purposes, does the example work?

One thing you may look at is the file format options.  Parquet does not have some of the file format options specified in your code above.
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#type-parquet

Comment: The example fails with the same behavior. It doesn't seem to be related to the options...

Comment: That is good to know.  Is it file specific?  Do you have an example file that repros the issue?